# Netbeans use Remote Server Git Working Copy

Tags: git, netbeans

I need to know if there is a way to manage with Netbeans a remote git working copy that is hosted in a Dev Server with out have a local copy for the project, so manage all commits with local netbeans for git working copy project hosted in Dev Server.

Any advice will be use full to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you can't just clone the remote git repository locally and then push your changes?  What you're describing is not a normal git workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the remote server uses some Unix or Linux variant, you can use [SSHFS](https://www.google.com/search?&q=sshfs) to mount a remote directory to a directory on your local filesystem. For most purposes it will be indistinguishable from any other directory on your local machine. In Ubuntu, you don't even have to use the command line; open the file browser, then go to the File menu, and select "Connect to Server", then select type "SSH", fill in the server name, folder to mount, and credentials (if needed) and you're good to go.