# Netbeans, GIT and remote server working together?

Tags: php, git, netbeans

I need help/advice on setting up a development workflow:

Editor:  NetBeans (latest version)
Project: remote PHPproject
GIT: locally cloned project
Workstation: Windows
Remote Server: Linux

I cannot run this project on Windows so I cannot use a local web-server.

I have reviewed:

[Netbeans use Remote Server Git Working Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15213706/netbeans-use-remote-server-git-working-copy)

[Using Netbeans on local and git (client) on remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25748420/using-netbeans-on-local-and-git-client-on-remote-server)

And they do not provide a solution.

I am on windows and the remote server is Linux.

I tried using WSL and mounting the git repo into WSL.  This worked, however WSL I/O is horrendous and running the webroot on a windows share is slow.  From what I understand, this also affects Docker.

I can commit changes in NetBeans, but this requires extra steps and I am not sure what exactly NetBeans is committing (ie the active file in the editor).

I would like to be able to simultaneously save to my local git repo or commit to my dev branch and save to the remote server.  Saving to the remote server is for testing purposes.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use jenkins to deploy into a server.... and I think a lot of people use Jenkins that way.

I am working on a project that can show on the File System the contents of a branch from a local repo:

https://github.com/eantoranz/gitmod

So on the linux server, you can ask gitmod to mount the branch X from a repo on the linux server so that it shows up in /var/www/html/somedir (that is like standard debian/ubuntu directory to publish into apache).

Then from your local machine you can push into this remote repo into branch X and it would *automagically* show up on the linux server. Just be aware that this is *alpha* software.